# How to delete the previous data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I display the present data instead of getting multiple data.

I want to remove the previous data because whenever new data is stored on Firebase it copies the same data about 4 times.

I'm using a mobile app to send data to Firebase. I've changed `databaseref.once` to `databaseref.on` so it can be a real-time database however multiple data is stored on my table.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Firebase Realtime Database Web</title>
 <script>
 // firebase config here
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Police Station 1</h3>
 <table id="reports" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Email Address</th>
   <th>Caption</th>
   <th>Location</th>
   <th>Time</th> 
   <th>Picture</th>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <script>
  var tblUsers = document.getElementById('reports');
  var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('PP3/');
  var rowIndex = 1;

  databaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
   var childData = childSnapshot.val();

   var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
   var email = row.insertCell(0);
   var caption = row.insertCell(1);
   var location = row.insertCell(2);
   var time = row.insertCell(3);
   var picture = row.insertCell(4);
   email.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Email.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
   caption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Caption.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
   location.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Location.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
   time.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Time.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
   picture.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Picture.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
   rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
});
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a `tbody` element to your table:

```
 <table id="reports" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Email Address</th>
   <th>Caption</th>
   <th>Location</th>
   <th>Time</th> 
   <th>Picture</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="reportbody"></tbody>
 </table>
```

And then clear that before adding the data to it:

```
<script>
  var tblUsers = document.getElementById('reportbody');
  var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('PP3/');
  var rowIndex = 1;

  databaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    tblUsers.innerHTML = '';
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
     var childData = childSnapshot.val();

     var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
     ...
```

Note that while simple, this is not  very efficient, so you may see some flicker. If that is a problem, consider listening for `child_` events in Firebase, which give you information to more precisely update the table, instead of the brute force refresh above.

Comment: Hello sir Frank Good day! thanks for answering my question. Im new to firebase and javascript language but your answer solved my questions immediately thanks again God bless ^^

Comment: Btw sir I've gotten the url for my image. is there any way where I can display it on the table?